# UINavigationController nested Inside UINavigationController (UITabbarController more tab)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having a issue where I have a UINavigationController as a tab on my UITabbarController. It works perfectly when it's a normal tab on the tab bar, however when it is placed inside the more tab and selected the app crashes with the message "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]"

Is this because there are nested uinavigationcontrollers? 
here is a image of the call stack.

[image]

Comment: Add an exception break point (http://screencast.com/t/pgAngZWX) check where it is crashing, and add the code to your question, so that people can check the issue

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/E8qNi1k.png

Comment: can you add your code